# Time Complexity of the Kruskal Algorithm after sorting

Tags: graphs, time-complexity, trees, minimum-spanning-tree

In case I have sorted edges already, What is the best time complexity of Kruskal Algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Almost linear in term of the number of edges of the graph.**

More specifically, here is the quote from [Wikipedia entry on Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm).

> Provided that the edges are either already sorted or can be sorted in linear time (for example with counting sort or radix sort), the algorithm can use a more sophisticated [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to run in $O(E \,\alpha(V))$ time, where α is [the extremely slowly growing inverse of the single-valued Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse).

Here $E$ stands for the number of edges in the graph and $V$ stands for the number of vertices in the graph. In fact, $\alpha(n)$ is less than 5 for any practical input size $n$, since  $\alpha$ is the inverse of the growing function $f$ and $f(1)=3$, $f(2)=7$,$f(3)=61$, $f(4)=2^{2^{2^{2^{16}}}}-3$, a number whose number of digits is a number whose number of digits is 19727 (all fractional parts ignored). In other words, even if $n$ has trillions of trillions of digits, $\alpha(n)$ is still 4.

Please note in computer science, this factor $a(V)$, however slowly grows, represents a real barrier to achieve a linear algorithm even after the edges have been sorted by weight.